# Colocar barra fixa encima de uma div com titulo

Tags: php, html5, bootstrap-3

estou com dificuldades em colocar um barra fixa encima de uma div, e deixar a mesma responsiva, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue a imagem de exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste o que já tentou fazer, por favor.

Comment: De qualquer modo, fiz um exemplo simplificado no codepen: http://codepen.io/Gabcoder/pen/vyagRM

Comment: @GabrielRanéaBarbosa o exemplo que você me passou é parecido com o que espero, mas barra deve pegar parte da div no caso sobrepor e ser responsiva, mas obrigado pela força.

Comment: Coloque o código que estas a testar...

Comment: @MagicHat infelizmente eu não tenho o código essa imagem que eu passei não é de um pagina pronta, mas o que eu gostaria de fazer é somente uma pagina com uma barra encima cobrindo uma parte da div com um caption na barra.